# Unable to navigate in Jetpack Compose if arguments supplied has special characters in it

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

```
Navigation destination that matches request NavDeepLinkRequest{ uri=android-app://androidx.navigation/testScreen/Can I change this (Pin / Password)?/100/300 } cannot be found in the navigation graph
```

where

*Can I change this (Pin / Password)?*

is the title for my screen.
I get an exception while trying to navigate. How can I avoid this issue as my title contains ' / ' which is getting considered as part of the deeplink itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Special characters are not supported in url based navigation in compose.

If you feel there is a special character in your string argument. You can try encoding it to `java.util.Base64`

```
val titleArg = Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(title.toByteArray())
```

And then send this `titleArg` as a navigation argument or path

While receiving it just do a decode like this

```
val title = String(Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(titleArg))
```

Comment: In my case `encodeToString` also added a new line (`\n`) and I had to remove it with `.replace("\n", "")` or else it wouldn't work.

Comment: You might be receiving new line your String itself